# How to make the overflow button (the three dots) open settings right away?

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu, overflow-menu

I do not want to show a menu for only Settings and About, that's why i want the overflow button to open (immediately when clicked) a unified Settings-About page, the same way Instagram does.

At first i thought i might just do a menu with one action that is set to always Shown and has the overflow button icon (the three dots). But there are a lot of icons for different themes and i also think this wouldn't be correct for devices with a menu button.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this:

1. Go to style, change your theme DarkActionBar to noActionBar.
2. Add the android design support to your gradle.
3. Add toolbar to your xml
4. Add Imageview or imageviewbutton inside your toolbar
5. Find the three dot image in drawable using image asset
6. Add your three dot drawable as src of your imageview.
7. Set oncClick then intent.